# How can the length of a normal vector matter?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Problem:

[image]

Solution:

[image]

Graph:

[image]

For part a, I understand mathematically why the value of c matters. What I don't understand is how it can possibly matter intuitively.

I get that $\overrightarrow { \nabla  } F(x_{ 0 },y_{ 0 },z_{ 0 })=(0,c,0)$ and therefore, c can't be any value. My question is: how can a tangent plane possibly depend on the length of the normal vector? If the vector is normal, then the length shouldn't matter because the vector will always be normal for all values for c except 0.

Comment: It doesn't matter. You don't *get* that $\nabla f(x_0,y_0,z_0)=(0,c,0)$, but rather seek such $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ that the equality holds (for the first part, that is).

Comment: That doesn't really help. I feel like you just restated the equation in different words.

Comment: We only needed $\nabla f||(0,1,0)$. Rephrased, that is $\nabla f=c(0,1,0)$ for some $c$.

Comment: user1251385, it's not that it matters which $c$ you get, but that the other two coordinates are zero. And they really don't have to be: you seek a point on the surface that has that property, and therefore the tangent plane at that point is parallel to the $xz$-plane.

Comment: $c$ has to be the length of $\nabla f$. The length of $\nabla f$ has to do with the spacing between nearby ellipsoids determined by similar implicit equations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to find all points on the surface where the normal vector points in a specified direction (along the $y$-axis), but the easiest way to calculate the normal vector (using gradient) not only gives you a direction, but full-fledged vector. In order to prepare for this, you need to look for places where the gradient goes out in a specific direction, *without* specifying from the start what length of vector you're looking for in said gradient.

Solving the equation $\nabla F(x_0, y_0, z_0) = (0, c, 0)$ gives you a curve parametrized by $c$ (in this case $(c/4, c/4, 0)$) for which the gradient of $F$ always has direction along the $y$-axis. Then you solve $F(c/4, c/4, 0) = 16$ in order to figure out where that curve intersects with your surface.

Comment: "but the easiest way to calculate the normal vector (using gradient) not only gives you a direction, but full-fledged vector." Thanks. That snapped me into an understanding. What are the effects of a tangent plane when you scale up and down $\overrightarrow { \nabla  } F$ but keep $\overrightarrow { \nabla  } F$ in the same direction?

Comment: @user1251385 The problem is that if you look for places where the gradient has a specific size (say $(0, 1, 0)$), you won't get a point _on your surface_ unless you're very lucky, so the plane containing that point with the normal vector $\mathbf j$ won't be a tangent plane.